# angularjs dynamic init via user input

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build an angularjs-app where some content is already sent with the first request and hence shown to the user before angularjs has even loaded. In case a user is very quick and already enters some data into a textbox (input type="text") then this data is lost once angular-js does the binding.

How can I prevent this?

Cheers,
Robert

**Edit** As an example, I could get the following from the server

```
<html>
...
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <div ui-view>
     <!-- start template which was sent with the initial request, corresponds to login.tpl -->
     <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="credentials.username"/>
     <input type="password" ng-model="credentials.password"/>
    <!-- end template -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider){
...
//at this point the input of the user is still in the textbox
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    resolve: {
        credentials : function(){
            var username = $('#username');
            if (username) {
                username = username.val();
            }
            //username is always empty, the binding process has already reset the input field
            return username
        }
    },
    url: '/login',
    templateProvider: function($templateFactory) {
        var username = $('#username');
        if (username) {
            username = username.val();
        }
        //username is always empty, the binding process has already reset the input field
        return $templateFactory.fromUrl("login.tpl");
    },
    controller: function(username){
        //username is always empty
    },
    data : {
        requireLogin : false
    }
});
...
});

app.run(function($rootScope) {
    //username is still in the textbox
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
        //username is not in the textbox anymore
    });
});
```

I am using angular-ui-router for routing. I tried to intercept the binding at several places. First I tried to get the user input in resolve (with jquery because I want the input before angular clears it, so I cannot use angular for this task), but the username is already empty at this stage.
I also tried to do it in templateProvider but that is even executed later and hence too late.
I have also tried to listen to $stateChangeStart in app.run but the username is also no longer in the textbox (yet, it is there in app.run at the beginning -- binding must occur somewhere in the meantime) 
I am pretty sure I need to intercept the binding somehow but I do not know how I can achieve it without putting a directive on each input field, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: in fact, your resolves don't make sense.  Why are you using JQuery here?

Comment: You're right, my mistake, resolve comes before templateProvider. But nonetheless, the textbox is already cleared at this stage. I am using jquery since I want to get the input of the user before angular has bind the model in order that I can initialise the model accordingly. I could also use pure javascript but surely not angular.

Comment: I'll try to clarify, a moment please...

Comment: it is send with the first request from the server. Meaning, I am visiting http://example.com/index.html and it already returns the template as shown above. I'll try to set up a jsfiddle, never done that before, so please give me some time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93480/discussion-between-claies-and-robert-stoll).

Comment: the transcript of the chat will be preserved while this question is alive, but a brief synopsis of the chat revealed the issue.  Unfortunately it didn't reveal a solution.  Basically, those two input fields are being removed from the dom and replaced with different input fields when angular loads the route into the `ui-view`.  there doesn't seem to be any logical way to "copy" the values already entered from these inputs into the replacements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution without using a directive. But I could achieve what I wanted with the help of a directive in combination with an additional service.

The source code can be found here:
https://github.com/robstoll/angular-pre-work/blob/master/src/pre-work.js

I basically place the template in an own element which I mark with the pre-data directive. The directive then caches the content as template -- probably similar to the <script type="text/ng-template"> tag, but the `pre-work` directive does additionally gather all ng-models placed on inputs and saves their `.val()` which then can be merged into a `$scope` with the additional service.

I think it works quite well -- try it out yourself, comments appreciated since I am fairly new to AngularJS: http://plnkr.co/edit/98AdSYCnwzIkqocDwlHq

The only thing which still bothers me is that I lose the focus when angular is loaded. I can get the element which has the current focus in app.run() but I do not yet know when to set it, where, in which code place respectively. But I guess I will find that out as well.

**Edit**

I could also solve the problem of loosing the focus. I needed to wrap the statement which sets the focus inside a $timeout (delay 1ms). Seems like angular needs to do something else first.
Here the code I am using

```
app.run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.lastFocusedElement = angular.element(document.activeElement).attr('ng-model');
    var deregister = $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
        if ($rootScope.lastFocusedElement) {
            $timeout(function(){
                var elem = document.querySelector('[ng-model="' + $rootScope.lastFocusedElement + '"]');
                elem.focus();
            }, 1);
            deregister();
        }
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to prevent showing stuff before angular is ready by [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) perhaps.